# Iterate over Store via Map

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

Via a Map Objects are added to a Svelte Store.

Every object has an ID and it should be possible to iterate over those IDs.
With
$entities.get("123").currentPage;

The current Page of this Object is returned.

How can I iterate over more than one ID such that the current pages of all objects in the store are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take those IDs into an array, and then map that array to the code you listed in your question. For example:

```
function getPages(ids) {
    return ids.map(id => $entitites.get(id).currentPage);
}

// example call:
let pages = getPages(["123", "146", "195"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That does make a lot of sense. To specify my question: The ID of an object changes reactively and all the time and is also in the store, so I'd have to get them out of the store first, then add them to an array and then get the pages...any tipps? (I'm quite a newbie, sorry!)

Comment: That is another question. But yes, you'll need to get those IDs first of course. If you have trouble implementing that (after trying first of course), I suggest you ask a new question, where you explain *that* problem, providing the code you are using.